# passing data from html to php

Tags: php

dear all
I am a beginer in PHP world (PHP 5.3.5) my web server is IIS fastCGI on win xp
I tried to pass values from the HTML form to the php but the data are not passed

### this is my html file

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### and this is my php file welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

</body>
</html>
```

---

After pressing submit the output was like this

> Welcome!
>   You are years old.

but it should be like this

> Welcome John!
>   You are 28 years old.

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: it looks like working fine..so please put your code.

Comment: on your server, create a php page with <? phpinfo(); ?> in it - use that to test if your server is setup correctly for php usage.

Comment: The code has no errors, works fine.

Answer (score 3):

on IIS change in the form: method="post" to method="POST" <-- UPPERCASE should solve your issue.

Anyway what about the apache? and PHP version around just 5, flat five :)
5.3.5 on IIS for the beginner? sounds like to get the Mount Everest by night without gloves

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty standard simple code, and looks correct.  One thing you might look at is the way PHP is configured on your server.   Also, try using $_REQUEST in place of $_POST on your welcome.php page and see if it still does the same thing.

Try naming your form as well

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code it seems that it must be a configuration issue.

Steps to resolve this:

Firstly is the code that spits out the page actually `welcome.php`

Secondly add the following to your php block

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Click submit and if this still shows

```
array (
)
```

if so then do

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

and post the contents to your post, and show us.